# iOS framework with embedded Kotlin Multiplatform framework fails AppStore upload "Invalid Bundle"

Tags: ios, app-store, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m building a third party framework that is composed of a KMM framework that I embed and wrap inside of the main iOS framework using the [embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/07/multiplatform-gradle-plugin-improved-for-connecting-kmm-modules/) gradle task. This has worked like a charm for development, however when deploying an app with this framework to the Apple AppStore, we get the message:

*“Invalid Bundle. The bundle… contains disallowed nested bundles.”*

What’s strange is this works fine on simulator and even on devices. It seems to be purely an AppStore restriction. I know the obvious way to fix this is to deploy the KMM framework as completely separate public module, and then force the app to load it as a separate dependency.

Is there any other known way of handling this so I can keep the KMM framework as a private dependency of the main iOS framework?

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found was to ditch the `embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode` gradle task and instead write my own task that builds a static fat framework and links it, but doesn’t embed it.

Start by importing FatFrameworkTask and Framework:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.FatFrameworkTask
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.Framework
```

Then inside your kotlin directive, create a new FatFrameworkTask that will eventually be run from XCode:

```
tasks.register<FatFrameworkTask>("linkFrameworkForXcode") {
    println("LinkFrameworkForXcode")
    group = "build"
    val configuration = (System.getenv("CONFIGURATION")
    val platform = System.getenv("PLATFORM_NAME")
    val archList = System.getenv("ARCHS").split(" ")
    println("Configuration $configuration")
    println("Platform $platform")
    println("Architecture $archList")

    val targetMap = mapOf(
        "iphonesimulatorx86_64" to <replace with iosX64 target>,
        "iphonesimulatorarm64" to <replace with iosSimulatorArm64 target>,
        "iphoneosarm64" to <replace with iosArm64 target>,
        "iphoneosarm32" to <replace with iosArm32 target>)

    val frameworks = mutableListOf<Framework>()
    for (arch in archList) {
        val nativeTarget = targetMap["$platform$arch"]
        if (nativeTarget != null) {
            frameworks.add(nativeTarget.binaries.getFramework(configuration))
        } else {
            println ("Error: No mapping for architecture $platform $arch")
        }
    }
    destinationDir = buildDir.resolve("xcode-frameworks/$configuration")
    println("Destination: $destinationDir")
    from(frameworks)
}
```

For the `targetMap` be sure to replace the angle brackets with references to your iOS  targets that you've created for your kmm project. This is going to ensure the any/all of the targets requested by Xcode are merged into a fat framework as needed at build time.

Since we don't want to embed the kmm framework, we should set the framework to be static. In your binaries block:

```
binaries {
  framework {
    isStatic = true
  }
}
```

Next, open the build settings your Xcode project. Set the **Other Linker flags**: `-framework shared`. Shared here is the name of your framework, that is configured in the build.gradle(.kts) file of the KMM module. Also in your build settings, set **Framework Search Path**: `$(SRCROOT)/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/$(CONFIGURATION)`. Be sure to change the path as needed to point to your KMM module's build folder.

Finally, add a new 'Run Script' phase to your build phases. This should come before 'Link Binary with Libraries' phase. Use this to call out to gradle and run the task we just created:

```
cd <path-to-kmm-project>
./gradlew :shared:linkFrameworkForXcode
```

After a clean and build and you should have a framework that's linked with your KMM module and ready to be deployed in an app to the AppStore.

Comment: Thank you *so* much. There is no documentation about importing KMP modules into sub-frameworks in iOS. We had the same error as yours but made some adaptation for your script :
- Our main iOS target is keeping the `embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode` build phase gradle script for building the KMP modules
- We let the `isStatic` to `false`
- We adapted the paths to match the KMP documentation, `destinationDir = buildDir.resolve("xcode-frameworks").resolve(configuration).resolve(sdkName)`, `sdkName` being `System.getenv("SDK_NAME")`